# upload tmp folder

Tags: upload, temporary-files

when upload an image is stored in tmp folder, but because i am in shared hosting i can not change the upload_dir in php.ini.

Is it possible after image store in common tmp folder show it to user

```
<img src="path to tmp folder" />
```

(Which is the path to tmp folder)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) to move the file to your own directory.

Comment: thats what i am using now, but that means that i have to clean up my folder and server's tmp clean up by server

Comment: +1 because on almost every server the `/tmp` folder isn't publicly accessible.